# PHP - Como ordenar valores de uma tabela de loteria

Tags: php, php-7

Estou com o seguinte problema:
-imaginemos que temos os registos de uma loteria, mas precisamos de ordenar os valores. Já tentei o código da documentação do `php` - `asort`, mas não funciona!
Estou a usar a versão `7.2.4` do `php` (espero que não tenha um bug)!

Base de dados:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero ordenar os numeros que estão em `n1`, `n2`, `n3`, `n4`, `n5` e `n6`.

Ex: o registro `id=2032`, deveria ter `n1=6`, `n2=14`, `n3=19`, `n4=20`, `n5=39` e `n6=53`.

**Código:**

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM table32");
while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) { 
    $valores = array(
        "n1" => $dados['n1'], "n2" => $dados['n2'], 
        "n3" => $dados['n3'], "n4" => $dados['n4'], 
        "n5" => $dados['n5'], "n6" => $dados['n6']
    );
    asort($valores);
    foreach ($valores as $n => $val) { 
        echo "$n = $val"; //Não chega aqui! 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Poderia disponibilizar o código que você usa para inserí-los na db?

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `table32`");

while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
 $valores = array("n1" => $dados['n1'], "n2" => $dados['n2'], "n3" => $dados['n3'], "n4" => $dados['n4'], "n5" => $dados['n5'], "n6" => $dados['n6']);
 
 asort($valores);  

 foreach ($valores as $n => $val)
 {
  echo "$n = $val"; //Não chega aqui! 
 }
}

Comment: acho que descobri, tinha um problema na ligação à base de dados.
affff

Comment: Caso tenha alguma dúvida em ordenar arrays, recomendo-te: https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_array_sort_num